# What is the fastest way to check if std::vector index is not out of bounds?

Tags: c++, stdvector

Often I want to make sure I am in bounds once at the top of my function body.
The different ways I do this are:

```
// I don't like this much as it stops the program when I may not want to
assert( idx < v.size() );

if( !(idx < v.size()) )
{
    // take corrective action ...
}

if( v.size() <= idx )
{
    // take corrective action ..
}
```

Between the second and third method (and maybe others), which is more efficient?

Comment: I don't think you should be worried about efficiency, and instead ought to be worrying abut which is *correct*.

Comment: I think you're worrying too much. This kind of thing won't cause a performance hit. Anyway, you might want to look at **C++ exceptions** (Google it).

Comment: A) Premature optimization is bad. There's no reason for you to care how long that takes because it isn't an issue.  B) If you really wanted to know, do each a few thousand times and time how long each takes.

Comment: @Brian Roach I totally agree that if you have a few tests like this it really does not matter much. But think of calling this check millions of times say when loading millions of data into a database

Comment: @karimjee: If you're really doing this millions of times, why don't you just profile each, and compare?

Comment: `idx` is of some unsigned type, right?  Otherwise you'd need to confirm that `idx >= 0`.

Comment: @karimjee: If you doing this millions of times loading stuff into a DB this is **NOT** going to be the bottleneck. The communication with the DB is going to be several orders of magnitude larger and cause many more processor hangs (thus any inefficiency in the checking will effectively evaporate to zero time). This is why doing premature optimization is dangerous (you have no idea weather this is even a problem until you time it so end up wasting time optimizing something that will never affect the overall time).

Answer (score 6):

Just use

```
idx < vec.size()
```

and be done with it. You're not going to make your application **any** faster by spending another minute on this issue.

Also, consider checked access:

```
try {
    vec.at(idx) = stuff;
} catch (std::out_of_range& err) {
    // oh dear god
}
```

Comment: This is not the same test though. I want to fail early; this test while correct may not be as convenient

Comment: I suppose the entire point of doing one check at the beginning is to *not* have to use checked access later on...

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time you are not going to check. **Because you have already validated the user input** at the point where it enters the program thus you should not need to check anywhere else.

If there is any possibility that unvalidated input is being used then you should be using the method at(). This will throw an exception if the index is out of bounds and behave like operator[] in all other situations. The exception will cause the application to quit unless you explicitly catch and compensate (which you should only do if that is a valid option otherwise let the application exit (maybe with an error message if appropriate)).

Personally I much prefer to use exception instead of asserts().
Asserts can be turned off at the compiler level (so they are useless in production code (only good for testing the code is valid in unit tests)), exceptions provide the same functionality (quick shut down of the application if they are triggered (and like exceptions they allow you to log info)). Unlike asserts exceptions can be caught if appropriate (though mostly you just want to let them kill the application)).

Comment: `.at()` has runtime overhead even if you have validated the user input previously. `assert` helps you make sure you got the validation right while developing and doesn't cost you anything in release mode.

Comment: @Ayxan Sure. But assert does not protect you if there is an error in production. If there is any chance of an unvalidated index you need to use `at()`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looping over this vector.  If the function for which you're writing this code isn't being called in a loop or something, just don't worry about it.  Both statements compile to the same 3 or 4 instructions, depending on your compiler's vector implementation.  If the function IS being called in a loop, do two things: make it inline, and get rid of the check.  Instead, check the index against the boundary in the calling function.

Also, just don't worry about it, because something else is your bottleneck.  Look at your API calls, use of virtual functions in loops, float to int casts, sort procedures, thread synchronizations... trust me, this isn't going to hurt.